# What's the nature of this series? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{n^b}$, for $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you help me with this series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{n^b} \quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

For what a and b, the series converges?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve your understanding, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3450798/edit) to add details.

Comment: You need to make the question more specific.

Comment: Do you want to know for what $a$ and $b$ the sequence converges?

Comment: Exactly. I will change the question right now.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$s(a, b, m)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{n^b}
$
and
$s(a, b)
=\lim_{m \to \infty} s(a, b, m)$
if the limit exists.

If $a, b > 0$
then
$(n+1)^a-n^a
\approx a n^{a-1}
$
so
$s(a, b)$
exists if
$b-a+1 > 1$.

I'll leave the other cases
for you.